# How do I get started with turning columns into rows in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have this table in CSV. MOL stands for Male and FOL stands for Female. The second part SAL_Tagalog is the language and SOLSE_NotWell means they do not speak the language well, whereas SOLSE_Well means they speak it well.

```
MOL_SAL_English_SOLSE_NotWell   FOL_SAL_English_SOLSE_Well  Postcode    State   Year
                0                              8                2600       ACT  2016
                0                              9                2601       ACT  2016
                0                              16               2602       ACT  2016
                0                              7                2603       ACT  2016
                3                              6                2604       ACT  2016
                0                             20                2605       ACT  2016
```

I need to turn each cell into its own row like below:

```
Sex          Language         Proficiency        Count    Postcode      State      Year 
Male         English           NotWell            0        2600          ACT       2016
Female       English           Well               9        2600          ACT       2016
Male         English           NotWell            0        2601          ACT       2016
Female       English           Well               9        2601          ACT       2016
```

Can anyone help me on how to approach this?

So far, I have a function that splits the column names by "_" so I end up with [MOL, SAL_English, SOLSE_NotWell]. These are mean to go into the cells of my new CSV.

I am currently trying to write it row by row into a new CSV file with the columns Sex, Language, Proficiency, Count, Postcode, State and Year. This is seen below but I am unsure of how to get the relevant Postcode and State etc.. from the same row.

```
for column_name, count in df.iteritems():
new_df.Language = column_name
new_df.Count = count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run it using Pandas' built in tools : 
Flip the column from wide to long, using pandas' [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) method this allows easier extraction of details
The rest is a combination of pandas [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#method-summary),[regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
 #mapping for sex column which we'll create
 sex_map = {'MOL':'Male', 'FOL':'Female'}

(df
#flip the columns from wide to long
.melt(id_vars=['Postcode','State','Year'],value_name='count')
#extract the required columns
        #sex is either MOL or FOL, which is the first characters before _
.assign(Sex=lambda x:x.variable.str.split('_').str[0],
        #proficiency is the grp of characters after the last _
       Proficiency = lambda x: x.variable.str.split('_').str[-1],
       # a bit of regex here, 
       #basically get the word between SAL_ and _SOL
       Language = lambda x: x.variable.str.extract(r'((?<=SAL_).*(?=_SOL))')
       )
 #use the sex_map dictionary to get the right entries(male|female)
.assign(Sex = lambda x: x.Sex.map(sex_map))
 #remove the unwanted column
.drop('variable',axis=1)
)
```

And here is another option, but possibly longer: it is a combination of [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and string methods.

```
  sex_mapping = {'MOL_SAL':'Male', 'FOL_SAL':'Female'}

(pd.wide_to_long(df,
               stubnames=['MOL_SAL','FOL_SAL'],
               i=['Postcode','State', 'Year'],
               j='proficiency',
               sep='_',
               suffix='[\w_]+'
               )
.stack()
.reset_index()
.rename(columns={'level_4':'Sex',0:'count'})
.assign(language = lambda x: x.proficiency.str.extract(r'(.*?(?=_))'),
        proficiency = lambda x: x.proficiency.str.rsplit('_').str[-1],
       Sex = lambda x: x.Sex.map(sex_mapping)
       )
 )


  #first couple of rows

  Postcode  State   Year    proficiency Sex    count    language
0   2600    ACT    2016      NotWell    Male    0.0     English
1   2600    ACT    2016      Well       Female  8.0     English
2   2601    ACT    2016      NotWell    Male    0.0     English
3   2601    ACT    2016      Well       Female  9.0     English
4   2602    ACT    2016      NotWell    Male    0.0     English
5   2602    ACT    2016      Well       Female  16.0    English
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick and taught me many of Panda's possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of that common unfortunate scenario where the underscore `_` is being used both as a delimiter separating attributes and as a space character.

1. First, pull the postcode, state and year out into the index, just to get them out of the way.
2. Then, use a helper function to split your remaining columns into meaningful tuples
3. then upgrade those tuples it to a multiindex. At that point,
4. we're done - but we just need to reshape the data.

Use your helper function to parse the columns into tuples `(Sex, Language, Proficiency)`. I also add a fourth element here to indicate what kind of data it is - this ends up being the "Count" in your final data. 
The helper function you have to write is usually complicated and challenging.

```
# Helper function
def helper_function(name):
    #Use the first character to get the gender
    if name[0] == 'F':
        sex = 'Female'
    elif name[0] == 'M':
        sex = 'Male'
    else:
        sex = 'Other'
    # The third word is the language
    lang = name.split('_')[2]

    # The last word is the proficiency
    prof = name.split('_')[-1]
return (sex, lang, prof,'Count')
```

Applying that to a column name will allow us to split out the important details.

```
# Step 1
new_df = df.set_index(['Postcode', 'State', 'Year'])
# Step 2
column_tuples = [helper_function(name) for name in new_df.columns]
# Step 3
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(column_tuples, names=['Sex','Language', 'Proficiency', 'Measure'])
# Step 4
new_df = new_df.stack(['Sex','Language', 'Proficiency']).reset_index()
```

Multiindexes are worthwhile learning about!
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html

Comment: Thanks so much, will look into MultiIndexing :)